# power.t.test() returns negative delta for low power values

Tags: r

I just ran into some weird behaviour for R's `power.t.test()`, which returns negative `delta` ("true difference in means") values if I try to run it for low values of `power`. Here's a MWE:

```
power.t.test(n = 30,sd = 30,type = "paired",power = 0.01)$delta
[1] -2.073823
```

When I start gradually increasing `power`, the resulting `delta` increases monotonically - which is what I would expect if all values were positive, but which is totally weird if you think about negative delta values - for `type = "paired"` and `alternative = "two.sided"` (the standard) I believe the `delta` was supposed to be returned as an absolute value. Some more examples below:

```
sapply(X = (1:10)/100,
       FUN = function(x,...){power.t.test(power=x,...)$delta},
       n = 30, sd = 30, type = "paired",
       simplify = TRUE)
[1] -2.0738235 -0.5309280  0.4482013  1.1848257  1.7840618
[6]  2.2941601  2.7414432  3.1419327  3.5061993  3.8415337

power.t.test(n = 30,sd = 30,type = "paired",power = 0.02500001)$delta
[1] -4.235165e-22
```

My guess is that the approximated formula used by `power.t.test()` fails for low values of `power`. Any thoughts on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Felipe

Comment: Have you read the source code of the function? It's completely in R and shows how `delta` is calculated using the `unitroot` function. Might be a good start to understand why it's negative.

Comment: `powers <- power.t.test(n = 30, sd = 30, type = "paired", delta= seq(-2, 2, 0.0001))$power; min(powers)` yiels `0.025`. Setting the `power` less than the minimal power for test of size 0.05 is meaningless.

Comment: Also you see that `power.t.test(n = 30,sd = 30,type = "paired", delta = -2.073823)$power` =`0.05550338` is nowhere near to your  prescribed power `0.01`.

Comment: @Molx, thank you. I did take a look before, but my educated guess was (and still is) that the formula used by `power.t.test()` to perform the calculation is not valid for such extreme cases (regardless of the `uniroot()` portion of the routine).

@Khashaa, thank you too. But your answers also seem to concentrate on the behaviour of the function, which I know is inconsistent with what I expected. I think the exact formula for calculating the power using the non central t distribution:

t_{df;alpha/2} = t_{df;beta;ncp}

should allow for power values smaller than 0.025 in this case.

Comment: @FelipeCampelo The power `0.01` is unattainable in this case. How to you interpret the value `power.t.test(n = 30,sd = 30,type = "paired",power = 0.01)$delta`?